# Restricting a smooth vector bundle to a submanifold

Tags: riemannian-geometry

[image]
[[Vector Bundle Chart lemma]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cS4eR.png)

The above is an example in Lee's smooth manifolds.
My question is about the case where $S$ an immersed (or embedded) submanifold of $M$.
By the chart lemma, $E|_S$ is indeed a vector bundle.
Then is $E|_S$ an immersed (or embedded) submanifold of $E$?

In both cases, immersion of the inclusion map $i:E|_S \rightarrow E$ can be easily checked by coordinate charts in $E|_S$ and $E$.
So, how to prove whether the topology of $E|_S$ is the subspace topology of $M$?

Comment: $E\vert_S$ is *defined* as a subspace of $E$ equipped with the subspace topology. So the compatible charts are all you had to check.

Comment: There's a correction to this example in my correction list (https://sites.math.washington.edu/~lee/Books/ISM/).